# how to use below curl command in python

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

Below is the curl command and wanted to use in python by using request. I am beginner to python. Appreciate advice/help.

curl --header 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8' --data-binary @c:/abcd.xml -X POST http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) to POST data:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx'
files = {'c': open('/abcd.xml', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/#) is now a defacto standard.

Comment: Do you need more explanation? I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module or call it from a shell.
So,

```
from subprocess import call
call("curl --header 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8' --data-binary @c:/abcd.xml -X POST",shell=True)
```